# jquery click background pos Y + count++

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with overflow hidden with a set height and inside I have an image with position relative and top: 0px

I would like to know how I can add a count to css position top: 0px so every time the user click on the "up button", the image moves by 10px up within the div.

I can't seem to get the count++ to work, please see JS Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/michelm/wE2Tz/

```
//var count = 10++;

$('#button_up').click(function(){
    $('#banner img').css('top', '-10px') ;
});

$('#button_down').click(function(){
    $('#banner img').css('top', '10px');
});
```

Comment: Have you tried binding click with your logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
$('#button_up').click(function(){
    $('#banner img').css('top', '-=10px') ;
});

$('#button_down').click(function(){
    $('#banner img').css('top', '+=10px');
});
```

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nWT7N/).

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. It works great :)
 I tried that too but I had the syntax wrong. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$('#button_up').click(function(){
    var currentTop = $('#banner img').position().top;
    $('#banner img').css('top', currentTop - 10) ;
});

$('#button_down').click(function(){
    var currentTop = $('#banner img').position().top;
    $('#banner img').css('top', currentTop + 10) ;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3wEMz/